# Copying a large number of files from a remote device without creating an archive

Tags: networking, command-line, scp

Normally, if I wanted to copy files from a remote machine I would do

```
scp user@remote.device:/folder/* .
```

However, in this case there are so many files that get I the error

```
bash: /usr/bin/scp: Argument list too long
```

Now, from googling this problem I can find several ways to create a tar archive on the remote machine without triggering this error. However, in this case the remote machine only has a small SD card for storage so there is no space to create an archive.

So what would be the normal way to transfer the files in this case? I guess it shouldn't make much difference, but in case it does, my local machine is a Mac and the remote one is a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Since you are on a Mac check out this post and see if it makes it easier for what you are trying to do. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8950/copy-files-from-osx-to-from-pi/9818

Comment: @NetworkKingPin it might be worth trying as a last resort, but I want to avoid installing software on the other device as its storage is nearly full.

Comment: You have an answer, but for completeness the **other way** is to **transmit an archive without storing** e.g. `ssh user@remote 'cd folder; tar cf - .' | tar xf -`. On GNU tar and maybe others, `f -` (use stdout/stdin respectively) can be omitted. `tar` keeps original modtime by default, like `scp -p`; if you want it updated, add `m` after `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `-r` parameter of `scp`, so:

```
scp -r user@remote.device:/folder/ ./
```

Note that as a result, `folder` will end up as a sub-folder of `./`

Comment: It appears that this works! I'm surprised, because my files aren't in subfolders. It seems enormously faster than without the `-r` flag too. Do you have any insight as to why?

Comment: It sure works, because it's just the purpose of this parameter. :)   But I'm not really sure why it is faster this way.

Comment: Hmm, well according to the man page the purpose of the parameter is to recurse into subfolders. That's not the issue here - my files are not in subfolders - but it seems to work anyway so I'm not complaining! I hypothesise that the shell-glob version is opening a new ssh connection for every file and this one doesn't.

Comment: It seems that you understand the term "recurse" wrong. Recurse means files and subfolders, and files and subfolders inside subfolders and on and on.

Comment: No, I understand it just fine. My files are all in one folder, there are no subfolders.

Comment: It is faster with `-r` because the remote subsystem sends files to your locally running scp application (the process becomes initiated by the remote host, and your local host simply acknowledges as it receives), whilst without the `-r` first your scp builds a list of files, and then it asks the remote host for each file, one by one, creating a fair amount of networking latency.

Comment: It did not work for me even with -r