# scp, list of arguments is to long

Tags: scp

I tried to copy files from my device to local host.
I used scp and `scp -r` (like on this problem [Copying a large number of files from a remote device without creating an archive](https://superuser.com/questions/1065243/copying-a-large-number-of-files-from-a-remote-device-without-creating-an-archive)). Unfortunately, I still can not copy files.

Path which I use: `scp -r /home/file/data* host@IP:results`

Comment: Either break your list of files into smaller chunks, or get a copy tool that can accept a list of files on stdin.

Comment: I did it previously but it is ~0.5 milion files so it will took long time and I would like to find an answer how to do it without smaller chunks.

Comment: With the `-r` option, you're only passing directory names.  Do you have 500k directories?  In any case, this seems like you should be using an intermediate archive, since that should make the network transfer substantially more efficient.

Comment: 1 directory, 500k files

Answer (score 0):

A dirty and slow suggestion could be for files only

```
  for myfile in $(find /my/path - type f)
  do
  scp $myfile user@server:/path
  done
```

If you need to maintain the folder structure of your path you can use rsync

```
 rsync -aAvh /my/path/* user@remote:/remote/path
```